# Parameter optimization using a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, genetic-algorithm, labview

I am trying to optimize parameters for a known function to fit an experimental data plot. The function is fairly involved

[image]

where x sweeps along a know set of numbers and p, g and c are the independent parameters to be optimized. Any ideas or resources that could be of assistance?

Comment: I am currently trying to use the second differential of the experimental data to see if I can locate peaks. The c parameter as you can see centers the respective graph so if I am able to somehow locate the peaks from the experimental data, the c parameter can be analytically solved for..Also I did not mention above but the experimental data can be an infinite combination of the wave described by the above function, so it could involve an infinite set of p,g and c parameters which is why I am trying to solve for the c parameters before applying a genetic algorithm

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest. Have you tried asking on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) ("*For professional mathematicians*"), or [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) ("*For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields*")? You may well find you'll get more attention, and possibly some answers, there.

Comment: Why are you so sure you need a genetic algorithm? Have you tired old good [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) as implemented in Levenberg-Marquardt.vi. If it does not suite your needs, you can try [Waptia library](https://lavag.org/topic/10984-cr-waptia-genetic-optimization-algorithm/)for LabVIEW with one of the genetic algorithms implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I will try at MathOverflow too..I had heard that LMA often gets stuck in local minimums and misses the global minimum..The problem set is relatively small and I though that GA's would be able to get the global min in finite time,,I tried using the Waptia library but could not find good documentation on how o use it (i am a newbie)

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend Genetic Algorithms. Instead go for straight forward Optimization.

[Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) has some resources.

You haven't provided any data or so, so I'll just go for something that should run. Below is something to get you started. I can't know if it works without seeing the data. Also, there must probably is a way to dynamically feed `objectivefunc` your `x` and `y` data. That's probably in the docs to `scipy.optimize.minimize`.

What I've done. Create a function to minimize. Here, I've called it `objectivefunc`. For that I've taken your function `y = x^2 * p^2 * g / ...` and transformed it to be of the form `x^2 * p^2 * g / (...) - y = 0`. Then square the left hand side and try to minimise it. Because you will have multiple (x/y) data samples, I'd minimise the sum of the squares. Put it all in a function and pass it to the minimize from scipy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objectivefunc(pgq):
    """Your function transformed so that it can be minimised. 
    I've renamed the input pgq, so that pgq[0] is p, pgq[1] is g, etc.
    """
    p = pgq[0]
    g = pgq[1]
    q = pgq[2]
    x = [10, 9.4, 17] # Some input data.
    y = [12, 42, 0.8]
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sum_ += (x[i]**2 * p**2 * g - y[i] * ( (c**2 - x**2)**2 + x**2 * g**2) )**2
    return sum_

pgq = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.5]) # Supply sensible initivial values
res = minimize(objectivefunc, pgq, method='nelder-mead',
            options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem with scipy is that I am unable to install it..I am using WIndows 8.1 64 bit and have python 2.78..I tried pip and easy_install..I am able to import numpy, pyevolve but for some reason scipy always gives an error "....laplack/blas not found..." I tried following many solutions I found here but none of the worked for me. ..I am a newbie..This is part of the reason I am using LabView instead of Python

Comment: Don't tag your question Python if you don't want to use Python. Although clearly that is a problem which could be fixed. You'd probably need to install laplack/blas.

Comment: I am and want to make further use of Python, just am unable to use scipy library at this time..My plan was/is to use LabView as an interface (front panel) and write the GA/fitting algorithm in Python for its speed..Is there any other library similar to scipy? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd be surprised if your algorithm runs faster in Python than in LabVIEW. At least, any built-in functions in scipy or LabVIEW should be equally well optimised, and any code you write yourself should go faster in LabVIEW, which is compiled, than in Python which is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired old good [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) as implemented in Levenberg-Marquardt.vi. If it does not suite your needs, you can try [Waptia library](https://lavag.org/topic/10984-cr-waptia-genetic-optimization-algorithm/)for LabVIEW with one of the genetic algorithms implemented.

Comment: I had heard that LMA often gets stuck in local minimums and misses the global minimum..The problem set is relatively small and I though that GA's would be able to get the global min in finite time,,I tried using the Waptia library but could not find good documentation on how to use it (i am a newbie)